# Cook/make buckwheat

Tags: word-choice

Is another word necessary after "buckwheat" in my sentence? For example, "buckwheat porridge"  and do you cook or make buckwheat and do you cook or make buckwheat porridge?

1. "My favourite food is buckwheat. I can cook buckwheat, but I rarely cook it."
2. "I cook buckwheat."
3. "I make buckwheat."
4. "I make buckwheat porridge."
5. "I cook buckwheat porridge."

Comment: It sounds a little odd to this US English speaker to say "make/cook buckwheat" with nothing after it, because as Astralbee says, *buckwheat* is just a grain, and if you don't specify, it sounds like you're just cooking a pot of whole grains.  But it might be understandable in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, 'buckwheat' is a grain, and 'buckwheat porridge' is a dish made from buckwheat and other ingredients. Strictly speaking, you *make* the dish, but you don't *make* the buckwheat - it is grown, harvested, bought from a store. However, if 'buckwheat' is being used as an abbreviation of 'buckwheat porridge' then of course you could say "I make buckwheat". I wouldn't think it was unusual if someone said "I'm making eggs and bacon", or "I'm making pork and beans", because those are both names of dishes, or common combinations of things that comprise a meal. Only a pedant would pull you up for saying you can't 'make' something that is farmed.

The difference between "cook" and "make" is that the first implies only the cooking process (eg frying, baking, boiling) but the latter can mean all the preparation involved to create the completed dish (eg chopping, weighing, mixing). "Make porridge" sounds more natural, as you would be adding milk to the grain, stirring etc. "Cook porridge" could sound like it was ready-made and you just heated it. Consider this example - I might say "I cooked a chicken" if I just put a chicken in the oven and roasted it, but if I was making a whole dinner including a chicken and other ingredients I might say "I made chicken for dinner".

Comment: So all the five sentences are natural, aren't? And either "cook" or "make" is correct.

Comment: especially with "porridge" do you say make or cook buckwheat porridge?

Comment: @AntoniaA I've added some detail about that, hope it helps.

Comment: do you mean that "make" involves frying, boiling, baking etc too as well as chopping,. mixing, etc?

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes - to "make" a meal incorporates all the steps of preparation which could include cooking. And of course, you could "make a salad", but you wouldn't *cook* it!